# Не получается внести изменения в Базу Данных. MySQL, C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Сама база данных запрос видит и выдает

```
 Отображение строк 0 - 3 (4 всего, Запрос занял 0,0049 сек.) [Raiting: 0... - ...]
```

на мой запрос

```
DataBase db = new DataBase();
            MySqlCommand co = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `users` SET `Raiting` = @rai ", db.getConnection());
            co.Parameters.Add("@rai", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = Raiting.Text;
```

Comment: Вы команду создали, а выполнять ее не выполнили.

Comment: Здравствуйте. я ее привязал на клик по кнопке. Или это так не работает ?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.5.php

Comment: Кароч здоровья тебе и всех благ )

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery: просто выполняет sql-выражение и возвращает количество измененных записей. Подходит для sql-выражений INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.5.php

Answer (score 0):

`co.ExecuteReader();` вызови после MySqlCommand..